# How to make JavaScript to work when its code is rendered dynamically after performing an AJAX GET request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rendering

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and jQuery 1.6.2. I am trying to get JavaScript to work when its code is rendered as a partial template after performing an AJAX HTTP GET request. That is, I have the following code that performs an HTTP GET request:

```
# The 'articles.html.erb' file

var jqxhr = $jQ.get('http://www.my_web_site.com')
.success(function(data) {
  $jQ('#data_container').replaceWith(data);
})
```

and this is what returns the HTTP request performed to the `'http://www.my_web_site.com'` URL (*note*: this is a partial template within some JavaScript code):

```
# The 'info_articles.html.erb' file

<%= link_to 'Article link', article_path(@article), :id => 'article_link' %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $jQ('#article_link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
  });
</script>
```

After the `replaceWith` function correctly replaces the `data` somewhere in the web page related to the `articles.html.erb` template, the Javascript just rendered (that is, that contained in the `info_articles.html.erb`) doesn't work. In the above example I am referring to the `click` event handler: it simply doesn't work as expected.

Why does this happen? How can I solve that issue?

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in your console?  I would think the above code would work.  $jQ() is your reference to jQuery I'm assuming?  And $jQ() is an object off the window object?

Comment: @Kyle Rogers No, I have no javascript errors in my console. Yes $jQ is my reference to jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

use a jquery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) binding in the main document instead.

Comment: I would do that. But I would use delegate, it's faster.